# Keep same URL params after doPost()

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page that list information depending on url. 
For example, url can be : 
"http://localhost:8080/group?ID=27"
And the jsp will list all 'persons' of this specific 'group'.

In this Jsp page, (/WEB-INF/views/group.jsp), I have a form to add a new "person".
I just want that, after submitting the form, and adding the user in the DB, I come back to the first url :  "http://localhost:8080/group?ID=27", to see the list again, with the new user.

In my doPost() method, I have this:

```
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {

    InfoUser infoUser = new InfoUser();
    infoUser.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
    infoUser.setGroup_id(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("group_id")));
    infoUser.setDescription(request.getParameter("description"));
    infoUserDao.add(infoUser);

    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/group.jsp").forward(request,response);

}
```

But of course, after the doPost() method, I go back to group.jsp, which has this url : "http://localhost:8080/group"

Is there anyway to go back to "http://localhost:8080/group?ID=27" after posting ? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your information, this is the kind of code I used to solve the problem :

```
public void doPost( HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response ) throws ServletException, IOException {
    InfoPoint infoPoint = new InfoPoint();
    infoPoint.setName(request.getParameter("name"));
    infoPoint.setLength_id(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("length_id")));

    infoPoint.setDescription(request.getParameter("description"));
    infoPointDao.ajouter(infoPoint);

    int ID = infoPoint.getLength_id();
    request.setAttribute("infoPoints", infoPointDao.lister(ID));

    response.sendRedirect("/points?ID="+ID);
}
```

Hope it will help someone someday ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can either redirect the user to the correct address (which requires another request to be made):

```
response.sendRedirect("/group?ID=27");
```

Or, you can update the URL in the browser after the page loads, using JavaScript:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/group?ID=27");
```

Comment: Hello, and thx for your help. 
I know that I can redirect the user to the correct address, but the ID in the url is a variable. How can I add a variable in a redirection ?

Comment: How about `response.sendRedirect(String.format("/group?ID=%s", request.getParameter("ID")));`